# How to do cross browser testing for a web site

Tags: testing, cross-browser, web

when we develop a web site then we do not know how web site behave in other browser and also in a specific browser with different version. i have seen few web site is there where we can put our web site url and it generate image of our web site. those functionality is not good. so i like to know is there any free tool exist which give me browser like feeling where we can put our web site url and do the interaction with our web site.

i am looking for best free tool to test web site functionality and UI look. share the idea. thanks

Answer (score 2):

One tool i know is [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/). It offers free trial for half an hour. If you need more, just register again with new email or support them and buy this product. It also offers you to test local links on different platforms and browsers.

There is also [saucelabs](http://saucelabs.com/) that offers free testing for some browsers, but if you want to test local link then you need to buy it.

Also [crosbrowsertesting](http://crossbrowsertesting.com/) offers free trial. But it only supports mac osx 10.8 and windows 7 in free trial and a bunch of browsers and different versions.

Hope this info helped.

Comment: I saw the browserstack.com its good,but is there any open source tool available for cross browser testing

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried this: https://spoon.net/browsers ?
There are of course more containers than browsers.

If you need that feature in a long term purposes I would consider to setup your own containers e.g with help of Docker (https://www.docker.com/) or with Selenium Grid. If you automate UI tests, Selenium Grid will help you with parallel run and its distributions.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.equafy.com also has a free version.

Only MacOs is not available for free, but if it is for open source project this is included

I am affiliated with equafy.com.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of tools available on internet but really I do not trust on result which they produce. They are good but not perfect.

If you really want to do pixel precise testing of UI in diff.browsers then do manually testing OR you can make it automate using **selenium web driver & TestNG framework**. You can also use **selenium grid** for this purpose.

Kindly refer : [Cross browser testing](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-multi-browser-cross-browser/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of another sites. Maybe someone will find it helpful.

- [cloudtesting](http://www.cloudtesting.com/)
- [browserling](https://www.browserling.com/)
- [saucelabs](http://saucelabs.com/)
- [crossbrowsertesting](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/)
- [browsera](http://www.browsera.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Cross browser testing tools have progressed a lot in the past couple of years with some of the tools now offering automated solutions.

We've recently researched the market and put together our [list of the top tools](https://softwaretester.tools/cross-browser-testing-tools-list/) which are available today.

If you have any feedback or know of any additional ones which should be added, please do let me know.